# Short fiction about virtual pets

Tags: story-identification, sentience, virtual

This story was a longish novelette, or a shortish novella. I read it about 5 years ago, maybe a bit more. Since I almost never read magazines, it was probably in some collection, but I don't remember at all which one. So it could be much older than that, I really have no idea.

It is about virtual pets "living" in virtual reality, but they were self-learning pets. At the beginning they gathered a lot of attention and were very popular, but after a few years people started losing interest.

I think the point of the story is how sad the situation of these virtual but somehow sentient pets was when their owners stopped being interested in them. But I don't remember very precisely how the story ends.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quite possibly *The Lifecycle of Software Objects* by Ted Chiang as per [Online story about virtual pets and a woman who crusades to save them](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/195599/online-story-about-virtual-pets-and-a-woman-who-crusades-to-save-them/195600#195600).

> "The Lifecycle of Software Objects" follows Ana Alvarado over a twenty-year period, during which she "raises" an artificial intelligence from being essentially a digital pet to a human-equivalent mind.
>
> Ana, a former zoo trainer, is hired by a software developing company to assist in the training of digital creatures, named digients in the story, that are designed with a learning capacity similar to human children. Ana helps with the training and forms a close bond with Derek Brooks, a designer in charge of creating the visual appearance of the digients.
>
> Blue Gamma releases the digients in a virtual reality platform named Data Earth with a big initial success, but after several years, the popularity of the digients diminishes and Blue Gamma closes. Several of the employees form a group to keep active the digients active and learning; Ana keeps one named Jax and Derek keeps two named Marco and Polo. During these years, Derek develops unrequited feelings for Ana....